# Show title with date in event calander

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using [full calander](https://fullcalendar.io/) as an event calander. I want to show city title with date in event calander. But I can't see any option which can help me to achieve that.

I have attached an image, How the title with date should looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a content hook, `dayHeaderContent`, to add whatever you need to the day titles (headers).

Here's how you do it:

```
dayHeaderContent: function(arg){
   let placeTitle = document.createElement('h4');
   placeTitle.innerHTML = 'PRA';
   placeTitle.className = 'font-large city-title'; // add whatever class(es) you need/want
   let dayTitle = document.createElement('span');
   dayTitle.innerHTML = arg.text;
   return { domNodes: [
     placeTitle,
     dayTitle
   ]};
}
```

Documentation:

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-header-render-hooks
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection

Comment: Thanks for your answer buddy. I have upvoted it.
I have already solved the issue by another way.